# $.mobile.loadPage() and $("linkBtn").click() doesn't load <head></head> in jquery mobile with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am forcing an anchor click when the app starts if the user is registered already.
When I do this and move on to Page2, all the script src don't get loaded. 
I'm not quiet sure what is wrong here.. i believe i followed manuals to force links..

- **page1.html** is single-paged.html -> loaded first when app starts -> redirects to **page2.html** by page1.js below.
- **page2.html** is multi-paged.html

from **page1.html** to **page2.html** is directed by:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    $.mobile.loadPage("Page2.html");
    $("#startbtn").click();
});
```

Here is page1.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/page1.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <a href="page2.html" data-rel='external' data-role='button' id="startbtn">START!</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna copy paste from [Why aren't my scripts and styles loading?](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html)

> jQuery Mobile's AJAX navigation system only loads in the contents of
>   the page wrapper, the scripts and styles in the head are discarded so
>   you need to plan how to load and organize these assets.

More explaination

> This means that any scripts and styles referenced in the head of a
>   page won't have any effect when a page is loaded via AJAX, but they
>   will execute if the page is requested normally via HTTP. When
>   scripting jQuery Mobile sites, both scenarios need to be considered.
>   The reason that the head of a page is ignored when requested via AJAX
>   is that the potential of re-executing the same JavaScript is very high
>   (it's common to reference the same scripts in every page of a site).
>   Due to the complexity of attempting to work around that issue, we
>   leave the task of executing page-specific scripts to the developer,
>   and assume head scripts are only expected to execute once per browsing
>   session.

Possible solution: Insert your styles and script in parent page (`page1.html` in your case). Learn how to use `on` `live` methods in JQM.

Comment: if i include all .js and .css files in parent page, will 
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){}); be called multiple times? if so, how should i implement 'pageinit' functions on each page?

Comment: Use pageinit for particular page like `$(document).on('pageinit', "#page1",function () {` and `$(document).on('pageinit', "#page2",function () {` where page1 id is given as `<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme='b'>` & `<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme='b'>`

Comment: i see thank u. just wondering, is this kind of hack or is it the proper way to get around this kind of issue?

Comment: @Joon.P The refence link I gave you is an official link of JQM. and I haven't seen any other way till now to serve this purpose. Mainly single page architecture is used. Or Page can be divided with scripts too, then ajax loading of page won't work. Feel free to upvote & mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.